# How can I reference a string (e.g. 'A') to the index of a larger list (e.g. ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ...])?

Tags: python, list, encryption, string-comparison, caesar-cipher

I have been racking my brain and scouring the internet for some hours now, please help.
Effectively I am trying to create a self-contained function (in python) for producing a caesar cipher. I have a list - 'cache' - of all letters A-Z.

```
def caesarcipher(text, s):
    global rawmessage  #imports a string input - the 'raw message' which is to be encrypted.
    result = ''
    cache = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
         'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Is it possible to analyze the string input (the 'rawmessage') and attribute each letter to its subsequent index position in the list 'cache'? e.g. if the input was 'AAA' then the console would recognise it as [0,0,0] in the list 'cache'. Or if the input was 'ABC' then the console would recognise it as [0,1,2] in the list 'cache'.

Thank you to anyone who makes the effort to help me out here.

Comment: What are the `text` and `s` parameters for? Why is it getting the message from a global variable instead of the parameter? Also, you don't need `global` if you're just reading the variable, only if you're assigning to it.

Comment: Note that you can write that `cache="ABCDEFGH...XYZ"`.  Strings are iterable, too.  In this case, you don't even need the lookup.  `ord(c)-65` will give you 0 through 25 for the upper case letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
positions = [cache.index(letter) for letter in rawmessage if letter in cache]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with a list comprehension. Also you can get the letter from `string`.

```py
import string

print([string.ascii_uppercase.index(c) for c in "AAA"])
# [0, 0, 0]

print([string.ascii_uppercase.index(c) for c in "ABC"])
# [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: This will raise an exception if the input contains something that isn't an uppercase letter.

Comment: Well yeah. I'm not covering edge cases here. One could select the set of characters suitable to the expected input.

Comment: This would work great for my purposes as before the function is called I have already capitalised the entire string input. I see how outside of this it may cause some issues though. Thank you

Comment: The only reason I selected uppercase was because it matched your sample cache. I was just letting you know it is provided by the language. The package contains other collections too.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for i in list(rawmessage):
    result.append(cache.index(i))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?